How switch to pop up in Katalon
I need your help in Katalon Studio
I have pop up without title and I need switch to this pop up (I want click on the button in pop up)

So, I know there exists three options:
Switch To Window Title/URL/INDEX => but in my case there no Title and no URL and no Index >> so, what I should to do?
Thanks
I tried
WebUI.switchToWindowIndex('1')
also switch to iFrame and nothing helps :((( SOS!


I solved a problem :)
Just changed xpath for the button locator in pop up!
